# Wave equation: travelling solutions

Tags: partial-differential-equations, wave-equation

I know that $f(x-ct)$, $g(x+ct)$ and $f(x-ct)+g(x+ct)$ are all solutions of the wave equation
$$
\frac{\partial u}{\partial t^2}=c^2\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x^2}.
$$
This is easily shown using the chain rule. How do I interpret this as left and right travelling functions? I'm having a hard time getting the picture of what's happening.

Comment: Do you remember how to shift the graph of a function to the left or right? Relate that to the $\pm ct$ term.

Comment: It just means that the wave moving left or right, or forward and backward in time are described by the same equation. Any solution will then be described by the superposition of these function, all depending on the boundary/initial conditions that you choose

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $f:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ and define $F :\mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}$ as $F(x,t)=f(x-ct)$. It will solve the equation. Pick your favourite point, for example $(0,0)$. If you watch the evolution of this point in time, you will see that its coordinates will satisfy $x-ct=0$, i.e. $x=ct$, so it will travel to the right. The argument is similar for the $x+ct$ combination.

Answer (score 0):

if you select a certain value of $f$, say $f_*$ when $x=x_*$ and $t=t_*$and then ask for what other combinations of $x$ and $t$ does $f(x-ct)=f(x_*-ct_*)=f_*$ you'll see that that happens when $x-ct=x_*-ct_*$ ... for that to be true, the relations $t=x/c$ and $t_*=x_*/c$ must hold ... meaning that $f=f_*$ when $x=ct=x_*=ct_*$